# NoClassDefFoundError Exception During when creating intent for SearchActivity

Tags: java, android

Since I am still new to Android (having started 3 weeks ago), my MainActivity class is based on the deprecated TabActivity superclass (as I want to accommodate versions 10-12). In my MainActivity class, I have created five main intents, with three of them intended to be Activities based on the FragmentActivity (there will be lots of drilldowns anticipated).

This is my MainActivity class code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.mexter.rewards2go.activities.main.FavoritesActivity;
import com.mexter.rewards2go.activities.main.ImageListActivity;
import com.mexter.rewards2go.activities.main.SearchActivity;

public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {



@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Resources resources = getResources();
        final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();

        final Intent imageIntent = new Intent().setClass(MainActivity.this, ImageListActivity.class);
        TabSpec tabHotDeals = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_IMAGE).setIndicator("", resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_promotion_off_btn)).setContent(imageIntent);

        final Intent searchIntent = new Intent().setClass(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
        TabSpec tabSearch = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_SEARCH).setIndicator("", resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_search_off_btn)).setContent(searchIntent);

        final Intent favoritesIntent = new Intent().setClass(MainActivity.this, FavoritesActivity.class);
        TabSpec tabFavorites = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_FAVORITES).setIndicator("", resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_favourite_off_btn)).setContent(favoritesIntent);

        Intent aboutIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, AboutActivity.class);
        TabSpec tabAbout = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_ABOUT).setIndicator("", resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.wip_info)).setContent(aboutIntent);*/

        tabHost.addTab(tabHotDeals);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSearch);
        tabHost.addTab(tabFavorites);

    }
}
```

As said, the SearchActivity is a sub-class of a FragmentActivity that is something like this (note that the Support v4-related libraries are specified.):

```
public class SearchActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Search Activity";
    Fragment fragment;
    //Temporary placeholder.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_layout);

        final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

        ImageButton bankButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bank_button);
        ImageButton merchantButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.merchant_button);

        merchantButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(fragment == null){
                    fragment = new SearchMerchantFragment();
                    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment);
                }
            }
        });

        bankButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(fragment == null){
                    fragment = new SearchBankFragment();
                    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment);
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

When running the app via the emulator, the system crashes, with the main reason being that it is unable to detect the SearchActivity class. It will work though, if I do not use the FragmentActivity inheritance.

Here's the stack trace:

```
06-03 17:53:14.156: E/AndroidRuntime(588): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 17:53:14.156: E/AndroidRuntime(588): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mexter.rewards2go.activities.main.SearchActivity
06-03 17:53:14.156: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at com.mexter.rewards2go.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
06-03 17:53:14.156: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-03 17:53:14.156: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-03 17:53:14.156: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-03 17:53:14.156: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-03 17:53:14.156: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-03 17:53:14.156: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 17:53:14.156: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-03 17:53:14.156: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-03 17:53:14.156: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 17:53:14.156: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-03 17:53:14.156: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-03 17:53:14.156: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-03 17:53:14.156: E/AndroidRuntime(588):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The fragments in relation to the SearchActivity class is already written and declared inside the Search layout xml file. Project properties including use of the support v4 related libarries have also been checked.

I am still unsure whether I have missed out somewhere in MainActivity or the SearchActivity class.

Comment: which line is `line 39` in mainActivity ??

Comment: Schnizel: Line 39 would be:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out, and it might resolve your issue.
https://plus.google.com/110296148724389171136/posts/7R2h3gCzi1k

Answer (score 0):

A little tweaking:

Turn on the checkboxes - Android Libraries and Dependencies in Order and Export tab of Java Build Path. Then do a Fix Project Properties.